# Разработать объектную модель

Tags: c#, ооп

Есть файл, в котором идет неизвестное кол-во строк, в которых задаются данные людей в порядке `Id;LastName;FirstName;BirthDate`. После пустой строки идет описание отношений между людьми. Возможные типы отношений: spouse - супруг/супруга, parent - родитель, sibling - брат/сестра. Формат строки с отшениями: по обе стороны от оператор "<->" задаются люди, которые состоят в отношениях, после знака равенства идет тип отношений, в которых эти люди состоят.

Само задание:

1. Разработать объектную модель по описанию выше
2. Разработать метод, чтобы для каждого человека можно было узнать в каком типе отношений он состоит с другим человеком. Например, у файла ниже для людей с Id 1 и 2 должен вернуться тип "sibling", хотя этого не было указано в файле явно.

Пример файла:

```
1;Иванов;Иван;01.01.1990
2;Иванова;Мария;01.05.1998
3;Иванов;Петр;01.01.1980
4;Иванова;Ольга;01.01.1971
5;Петрова;Маргарита;01.01.1972
6;Иванов;Олег;02.03.1995

3<->4=spouse
3<->1=parent
4<->1=parent
5<->3=sibling
6<->4=sibling
```

Помогите, пожалуйста с первым пунктом.

Я попробовал вот так, но второе задание с такими классами не решишь:

```
    public class Human
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string BirthDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Spouse : Human
    {
        public string Description { get; protected set; }

        public Spouse()
        {
            this.Description = "spouse";
        }
    }

    public class Parent : Spouse
    {
        public Parent()
        {
            this.Description = "parent";
        }
    }

    public class Sibling : Parent
    {
        public Sibling()
        {
            this.Description = "sibling";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Подумал можно записать по данным из файла всех людей в соответствующие списки: `List<Spouse` `List<Parent>` `List<Sibling>` и затем, когда пользователь вводит 1 и 2, то делать проверки по фамилиям и спискам, с помощью линку. Но даже если это будет работать, хотелось бы максимально правильную модель написать.

Comment: `Например, у файла ниже для людей с Id 1 и 2 должен вернуться тип "sibling" ` - интересно, почему вы так думаете? Человек с ID = 2 не состоит ни в каких отношениях с другими людьми, судя по информации из файла

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Обрезалась строчка файла! Извините. 3 и 4 супруги, их ребенок 1 и тут уже смотрим по фамилии, либо с одинаковой фамилией будет родитель, либо второй ребенок, по дате рождения ясно, что это второй ребенок, значит 1 и 2 будут брат - сестра

Comment: Это неправильно как-то с точки зрения законов мира. Одинаковая фамилия не гарантирует родство (сколько разных людей в мире с одинаковой фамилией?). В вашем условии четко написано, что отношение между людьми определяется в последней секции файла. Про однофамильцем ни слова нет

Comment: `хотя этого не было указано в файле явно` как вы тогда понимаете эти слова?  Я так думаю из этих слов и примера как раз `Например, у файла ниже для людей с Id 1 и 2 должен вернуться тип "sibling"`, ну и это усложняет задачу, но если вы хотите, то можем определять отношения только указанные в файле.  В дальнейшем, если учитель все-таки имел в виду мою версию, перепишу

Comment: Но с вами я согласен, просто тут мне кажется субъективное понятие задания, в этом дело

Comment: Это уже нужно будет уточнить у преподавателя. По структуре: нужно отдельно прочитать отношения в список объектов, затем создать класс, который будет "хитро" хранить эти отношения и иметь метод, решающий вашу задачу (на вход принимать два Human и возвращать тип отношения). Пока я сам не могу сказать, как оптимальнее будет хранить эти отношения, нужно поразмышлять

Comment: @AndreiKhotko `прочитать отношения в список объектов`, что вы имеете в виду, в `List<object>`, да и что вы под "хитро" имеете в виду не совсем понимаю, прям описание поверхностное довольно

Comment: @AndreiKhotko я вот пока вы отвечали придумал так:
Если строка содержит один из видов связи то считываем до = и записываем в соответствии с найденой связью в класс, затем считываем до и после <-> и добавляем по id в нужный лист.  При этом каждому человеку сделать лист, который будет хранить все его связи. Итого пользователь вводит айди двух людей, мы с начала смотреть с какими айди он связан, а затем какие у него связи

Comment: Да, идея в этом, но что если, допустим, есть две сестры Даша и Маша, и есть только запись о том, что Петя - родитель Маши. Ваш алгоритм в ответ на `Какие отношения между Петей и Дашей` выдаст `Отношений нет`, хотя на самом деле, Петя - родитель Даши (отец или отчим, в данной задаче это не суть). Нужно предусмотреть все неявные родственные отношения

Comment: Я бы еще выдавал результат независимо от порядка, в котором указаны люди, при ответе на вопрос

Comment: @AndreiKhotko это вы о том варианте, если заданы неявно?

Comment: Я бы не лез в неявные отношения, как минимум потому, что как вы по предложенному списку вариантов отношений определите например отношение типа "дядя", брат отца или матери, который, очевидно не является ни родителем, ни братом, ни супругом ребенка? Или [пра]*дед? И таких примеров можно привести массу. А для явных отношений нужно по сути два класса для имитации BD и класс Human с вложенными списками детей, родителей и линком на супруга. ИМХО конечно, остальное уточняйте у преподавателя. Максимум что можно достоверно выяснить неявно - брат или сестра по родителям, не более.

Comment: @rdorn Да, я неявностью я спрошу, класс Human просто со списком `List<Дети>` `List<Родители` и "линк на супруга", что вы подразумеваете? А вот про два класса для имитации, можете объяснить?

Comment: Можете ответ написать, приму, только расскажите, пожалуйста, что в этих классах будет и суть вашей идеи, она выглядит поэффективнее чем как решил я.